# How to reconcile context managers with the cell-based execution style of Jupyter notebooks?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, contextmanager

Notebooks like Jupyter split interactive execution into cells. Generally this works rather well for me, with a notable exception: context managers. If I open a `with` statement, the end of the cell closes the context, the context manager exits.

Say my notebook deals with data obtained from a DBMS. I would usually use context managers to manage the connection to the database and to manage cursors to automatically commit or rollback transactions. But then my entire code would need to be in a single cell after the connection is established.

The work around is to *not* use context managers, which the potential pitfalls context managers help us prevent. The problem is amplified IMO in notebooks when cells can be (indeed are) executed in any order. In my DBMS example, multiple connections to the DB could be opened without being closed because of the cell establishing the connection being executed multiple times. Furthermore, it is possible that their is not even an "inline" version of the context-manager, e.g. when the context manager is a `@contextlib.contextmanager` decorated function, although I have not seen that happening in any of the major libraries I use.

I am probably just ranting, but is there a way to make context managers cell execution friendly? Or are we just bound to either use short-lived context-managers and on our own otherwise?

Comment: One idea would be to collect long-lived context managers in a `contextlib.ExitStack` (you would still need to close this one manually).

Comment: Also, what do you mean by an "inline version"?

Comment: @ondra.cifka I mean using an object not as a context manager, if available. Like `h = open(...)` rather than `with open(...) as h:`.

Answer (score 2):

What about running the `__enter__` method of your context manager class in a cell?

```
from contextlib import ContextDecorator

class MyContext(ContextDecorator):

   def __init__(self, x):
      self.x = x

   def __enter__(self):
      return self
```

Then you could in any cell:

```
something = MyContext(10).__enter__()
```

That should keep you context "open" for the next cells.

You could use the same intuition for generator based context managers.

Comment: This is not reconciling notebooks with context managers, this is not using context managers altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I use the functions with context manager in Jupyter notebook ipynb files like this:

```
from node_vm2 import NodeVM

vm = NodeVM()
vm.__enter__()
vm.run() # do someting with vm
vm.__exit__(None, None, None)
```

Or try this one if you donnot want any magic function like me:

```
from node_vm2 import NodeVM


class VMContext(object):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.vm = NodeVM(*args, **kwargs)  # This VM class can be any class with its context manager.

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        return self.vm.__exit__(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)

    def open(self):
        return self.vm.__enter__()

    def close(self):
        return self.destroy()

    def destroy(self):
        return self.vm.destroy()  # return self.vm.__exit__(None, None, None) if exit func is not exist in the VM class.

vmc = VMContext()
vmc.open()
vm = vmc.vm
vm.run() # do someting with vm
vmc.close()
```